# Method not allowed exception. Laravel

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I'm having trouble with my routes.
I have following syntax:
Controller:

```
public function editFee($id)
    {
        $fee=fees::findorfail($id);

        return view('fees.edit',compact('fee'));
    }

    public function update($id)
    {

        $fee=fees::findorfail($id);
        // return $grade;

        // return Request::all();
        $fee->update(Request::all());

flash()->success('Successfully Updated!');
        return redirect('view');

    }
```

View:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
       <form role="form" method="post" action= 'update'>

        {{ method_field('PUT') }}
       {{ csrf_field() }}
           <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fee Type</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="fee_type" placeholder="Enter Fee Type Here" value={{"$fee->fee_type"}} required="">

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Amount</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="amount" placeholder="Provide Fee Amount" value={{"$fee->amount"}} required="">

            </div>




            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Update Fee</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </form>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('fees','FeesController@index');
Route::get('fees/add', 'FeesController@addFee');
Route::post('fees/store','FeesController@store');

Route::get('fees/view','FeesController@viewFee');
Route::get('fee/view/{id}/edit','FeesController@editFee');
Route::post('fee/view/{id}/update','FeesController@update');
Route::get('fee/update','FeesController@updateFees');
Route::get('fee/delete','FeesController@deleteFee');
Route::resource('fee','FeesController');
```

What is the problem here. When I try to go from @editFee to @update, it gives fillowing error:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

Can anyone help me here? I'm stuck!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form role="form" method="post" action='fee/view/{$fee->id}/update'>
```

instead of

```
<form role="form" method="post" action='update'>
```

The reason being is that the form must post to `fee/view/{$fee->id}/update` in order to get to the controller that you want.

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.